# I want to re-index whole collection in Apache Solr using Solrj client

Tags: oracle, apache, solr, solrj, relational

Take this scenario:

I have imported data from Oracle Relation table i.e. wlslog that contains 4 rows.
Now I am indexing those data from Apache Solr Console.
Now when I am querying this collection from Solrj it is fetching 4 rows as expeced.
But now I am adding 2 new rows from Oracle database to wlslog table.
But when I am calling this collection through solrj client.
It is fetching only 4 rows which I have imported once..

So is there any way in Solrj that we can get all 6 rows without doing re-indexing or re-data import. ?

let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Normally it's up to your application to add a document in Solr when a new DB row is added; is that what you meant?

Comment: @Yann>> Basically here things is like that there are some batch processes which is changing Database table(i.e. wlslog) or there are some forms which are updating database table(i.e. wlslog).. and same I want to update into Apache Solr database.. so is there anyway through which I can accomplish this ? I don't want to import all data every time through Solrj.. I just want to import all modified/added data into table to reflect into Apache Solr using Solrj Client.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that, other than your application (batch or interactive) updates the Solr index at the same time as it updates the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in a similar situation a long ago, an Oracle DB to be indexed and many sources of modification that can not be changed.
The final design is a trigger on the table to be indexed that reports all records changed or added to a queue. The queue is than polled by a dedicated process to update Solr.

If you have controls over the sources of modification than it is much simpler to modify thoses processes to update Oracle records and Solr index within a transaction.